# Solve the equation $R^{2}\frac{\arccos(\frac{h}{R})+\frac{h}{R}}{2} = \pi r^{2}$ for $R$

Tags: trigonometry, circles, quadratics, factoring

I have the following equation and I want to solve for $R$.

$$R^{2} \left( \frac{\arccos \left(\frac{h}{R}\right) + \frac{h}{R}}{2} \right) = \pi r^{2}$$

Comment: While not foolproof, usually if WolframAlpha doesn't return an answer, it's an indication that it may well not be possible without something rather elegant or convoluted. It seems to be the case here; you might have to resort to numerical approximation methods. (Wolfram: https://goo.gl/kwehDo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, this is a transcendental equation and you cannot expect analytical solutions and then some numerical method would be required.

We can make the equation looking nicer using $R=\frac h x$  and $a=\frac{\pi  r^2}{h^2} $which makes
$$a x^2-x-\cos ^{-1}(x)=0$$ and the solution is the intersetion of $f(x)=x\cos ^{-1}(x)$ with $g(x)=ax^2$. There is only one solution to the equation provided $a \geq 1$ and, for sure, the solution is in $[0,1]$.

For sure, if $a$ is large (that is to say $x$ small), you could use Taylor expansion to get
$$a x^2-x-\cos ^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi }{2}-a x^2-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ and ignoring the higher order terms solve either the quadratic equation giving as *approximation* $x=\sqrt{\frac \pi {2a}}$ or even the cubic  equation (but this would not be very pleasant).

So, for $a\geq 1$, use Newton method with $x_0=\sqrt{\frac \pi {2a}}$ for finding the zero of
$$f(x)=a x^2-x-\cos ^{-1}(x)$$
$$f'(x)=2 a x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-1$$
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Trying for $a=2$, this would give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.88622693 \\
 1 & 0.84308752 \\
 2 & 0.84055714 \\
 3 & 0.84055001
\end{array}
\right)$$

We could have a better approximation of the guess building the $[2,k]$ Padé approximant of the function and solve the resulting quadratic. Using $k=2$, this would give as an estimate
$$x_0=\frac{3 a \left( \sqrt{3\pi(96 a^3-\pi)}-\pi\right)}{72 a^3-\pi}$$ For $a=2$, this would give $0.856358$.

Another thing which could be done is to use series reversion and get
$$x=t-\frac{t^4}{6 \pi }-\frac{3 t^6}{40 \pi }+\frac{5 t^7}{72 \pi ^2}-\frac{5 t^8}{112
   \pi }+\frac{7 t^9}{80 \pi ^2}-\frac{\left(128+105 \pi ^2\right) t^{10}}{3456 \pi
   ^3}+\frac{2067 t^{11}}{22400 \pi ^2}-\frac{\left(704+189 \pi ^2\right)
   t^{12}}{8448 \pi ^3}+\frac{11 \left(98+407 \pi ^2\right) t^{13}}{48384 \pi
   ^4}+O\left(t^{14}\right)$$ where $t=\sqrt{\frac \pi {2a}}$ Applied again for $a=2$, this would give $0.841464$.  Using this, I am sure that Newton method would converge in very few iterations.

In order to check the quality of the approximation, let us give $x$ a value; from $x$, compute $a=\frac{x+\cos ^{-1}(x) } {x^2}$ then $t=\sqrt{\frac \pi {2a}}$ and recompute $x$ according to the last expansion. Below are rproduced some values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_{\text{given}} &  a & x_{\text{calculated}} \\
 0.05 & 628.310 & 0.0500000000 \\
 0.10 & 157.063 & 0.1000000000 \\
 0.15 & 69.7879 & 0.1500000000 \\
 0.20 & 39.2360 & 0.2000000000 \\
 0.25 & 25.0899 & 0.2500000000 \\
 0.30 & 17.4012 & 0.3000000004 \\
 0.35 & 12.7610 & 0.3500000031 \\
 0.40 & 9.74550 & 0.4000000194 \\
 0.45 & 7.67423 & 0.4500000998 \\
 0.50 & 6.18879 & 0.5000004337 \\
 0.55 & 5.08573 & 0.5500016534 \\
 0.60 & 4.24249 & 0.6000056758 \\
 0.65 & 3.58157 & 0.6500179206 \\
 0.70 & 3.05183 & 0.7000529960 \\
 0.75 & 2.61819 & 0.7501492859 \\
 0.80 & 2.25547 & 0.8004077547 \\
 0.85 & 1.94438 & 0.8511043677 \\
 0.90 & 1.66793 & 0.9030757253 \\
 0.95 & 1.40450 & 0.9596060077
\end{array}
\right)$$

A problem remains when $a$ is close to $1$. For that case, we can perform the Taylor expansion around $x=1$ to get
$$a=1+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-x}+(1-x)+O\left((x-1)^{3/2}\right)\implies x=1-a+\sqrt{2 a-1}$$

**Edit**

Since I suppose that you would like accurate results, you will be using Newton method.

Using a quick and dirty non linear regression $(R^2=0.999997)$, you could use for the wole range
$$x_0=\left(\sqrt{\frac \pi {2a}} \right)-\frac{117}{1426}\left(\sqrt{\frac \pi {2a}} \right)^5$$